# Adding flow type-checking to grunt server development workflow

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, flowtype

I have added `grunt-flow-type-check` to my `Gruntfile.js` and it is working within `watch`. How can I add a task to strip the flow-type-annotations out of the code sent to the browser?

flow server seems to do this automatically, but I would like to be using the flow checking within my existing grunt-server based development workflow.

Also, how can I also add custom interface files to be referenced by `grunt-flow-type-check` and not have to include declarations in my actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just set this all up myself a couple days ago.

To just strip the annotations, you have to use the react jsx transpiler.

Install the transpiler: `npm install -g react-tools`

Running the transpiler: `jsx --strip-types --harmony --watch src/ build/`

Using this as part of your grunt build is accomplished by using grunt shell. ([Grunt shell info](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell))

Grunt shell lets you use shell commands as part of your grunt build. In my case I use it to both run the type checker and the transpiler, before the rest of my js build.

My setup here will run the type checker and then strip the annotations if no errors were found:

```
    shell: {
        'flow': {
            command: [
                'cd path/to/your/js',
                'flow check --lib globals_lib'
            ].join('&&')
        },
        'transpile': {
            command: 'jsx --strip-types path/to/src/ path/to/dist/',
            stdout: true,
            failOnError: true
        }
    },
```

As for your second question. The `--lib` flag above allows you to have a file (or multiple files) that contain all your declarations. In this case I follow fb's example and just a have a globals_lib folder with a file called globals.js inside, which has all my declarations (jQuery, _, etc).

Comment: I'll check that out when I have that particular hat back on. Thanks